# How to use setInputMethod of InputMethodManager

Tags: android, android-input-method, android-inputtype

I want to set a custom soft keypad only to an EditText of an AlertDialog. So I have my custom keypad, and how to assign it to the mentioned list view?

Is [setInputMethod()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#setInputMethod%28android.os.IBinder,%20java.lang.String%29) is what I wnted? If so, how to use it??

Or any other possibility of doing this??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  You'd have to start an input method service via bindService and provide the binder from the service as parameter 1 and the id of the service as the second.

An easier way is to just apply android:inputMethod in the xml for the edit field.  You still need to code the custom keypad of course.  Its not something I would recommend doing unless you have a huge need for it, input methods are a pain in the ass and users like being able to specify their own-  they have their own favorite features (swyping, gesture commands, etc) that you won't support.